# D3.js IE vs Chrome SVG not showing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple [***D3 donut diagram***](http://colinwhite.net/Dash2.5/donut.html) with a .mouseover() event that updates an SVG:text element at the center of the donut hole. It works great...

[image]

Until I encounter users with IE 9, 10 and 11. These browsers won't render the center label. Is there a way to accommodate IE and show the center label in both browsers?

[image]

The HTML page is based on [***HTML5BoilerPlate***](http://html5boilerplate.com/) with the various shims to detect old browsers.

The [***D3 script***](http://colinwhite.net/Dash2.5/js/DailyCensus.js) seems pretty straight forward.

```
    d3.json("data/census.php", function(error, dataset) { 
    var h = 220,  w = 295;
    var outerRadius = h / 2, innerRadius = w / 4;
    var color = d3.scale.category20b();
    var svg= d3.select("#dailycensus")
                .append("svg")
                .data([dataset])
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h) 
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function(d,i) { return +dataset[i].Census; });

    var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.slice")
                .data(pie)
                .enter()
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "slice");

    var syssum = d3.sum(dataset, function(d,i) { return +dataset[i].Census; });

    var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr("class", "d3-tip")
                .html(String);

    var formatter = d3.format(".1%");

    svg.append("text")
            .attr("id", "hospital")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("y", -10)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .html("Health System Census"); // Default label text
    svg.append("text")
            .attr("id", "census")
            .attr("class", "census")
            .attr("y", 40)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .html(syssum); // Default label value

    arcs.append("svg:path")
        .call(tip) // Initialize the tooltip in the arc context
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); }) // Color the arc
        .attr("d", arc)
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
                tip.show( formatter(dataset[i].Census/syssum) );
// Update the doughnut hole label with slice meta data 
                svg.select("#hospital").remove();
                svg.select("#census").remove();
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "hospital")
                    .attr("class", "label")
                    .attr("y", -10)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .html(dataset[i].Facility);
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "census")
                    .attr("class", "census")
                    .attr("y", 40)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .html(+dataset[i].Census);
                })

        .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
                tip.hide();
// Return the doughnut hole label to the default label
                svg.select("#hospital").remove(); 
                svg.select("#census").remove();
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "hospital")
                    .attr("class", "label")
                    .attr("y", -10)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .html("Health System Census");
                svg.append("text")
                    .attr("id", "census")
                    .attr("class", "census")
                    .attr("y", 40)
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .html(syssum);
                })
```

Comment: Does replacing .html with .text throughout fix it?

Comment: Hmm... interesting. According to BrowserStack this seemed to work. I'll test it some more tomorrow. Strangely, the .html seems to work for the tool tips just not the center label. If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks! (UPDATED: But with a 25K+ reputation and an SVG subsystem peer reviewer, I'm not sure you need it! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace all the .html calls with .text calls. Generally innerHTML is for HTML things although browsers are giving it SVG support as everybody keeps expecting it to work.

Comment: ok, this almost works in IE - text is adding in element, but all ```<``` and ```>``` replaces by html escapes (```&lt;``` and ```&gt;```).

Comment: I used the [innerSVG polyfill](https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/source/browse/innersvg.js) and html() works in IE now!

Answer (score 4):

It's not immediately clear what is causing the issue, however setting the `.text` property instead resolves the issue after testing with Fiddler:

```js
svg.append("text")
    .attr("id", "hospital")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(dataset[i].Facility);
svg.append("text")
    .attr("id", "census")
    .attr("class", "census")
    .attr("y", 40)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .text(+dataset[i].Census);
})
```

After investigating the `<text />` elements directly in the Developer Tools you can see that setting the `.innerHTML` property doesn't render the results you'd expect, however `.textContent` does.

If this is working as expected in both Chrome and Firefox, I'll gladly open up an interop bug for the IE team to look into. We've been doing some SVG work lately, so I may find that this has already been discussed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and [innerSvg polyfill](https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/source/browse/innersvg.js) helps me. Now html() in SVG works in IE.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: For others coming across this answer now that Google Code seems to be mostly broken - you'll want to npm/yarn install [innersvg-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/innersvg-polyfill), and then import/require it. For example, `import * as innerSVG from 'innersvg-polyfill';` on webpack.